# If there is an empty value put ; in csv

Tags: php, csv, fopen, fputcsv

I am trying to put an array in a csv file. But some values are empty.
How can I set a ; (value) if its empty.

My function for the csv.

```
function csv($smaller)
{
    $csv = new Wefact();

    $fp = fopen('voice.csv', 'w');
    $headers = [
            'Naam',
            'Bedrijf',
            'Email(werk)',
            'Telefoonnummer',
            'Email(thuis)',
            'Mobiel'
    ];
    $csv->fputcsv2($fp, $headers, ';');

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($smaller); $i++)
    {
        $csv->fputcsv2($fp, $smaller[$i], ';');
    }

    fclose($fp);

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: simply and if empty check `if(empty($smaller[$i])) { /*your code*/  }` ?

Comment: I will edit my question and put the function there.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that [`empty();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-examples) will return true if the value is 0 so you're probably better off using something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($smaller); $i++) {
    if($smaller[$i] == NULL || $smaller[$i] == '')
        $csv->fputcsv2($fp, '', ';');
    else 
        $csv->fputcsv2($fp, $smaller[$i], ';');
}
```

Comment: Its not putting the data in that field of the csv file it just duplicate values.